# Custom cell / table view

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to learn tableView and custom cell. I was able to find some tutorials.
However, I need to be able to have informations to go from a cell to another, when the users are editing informations.
I also have a problem implementing the code like an Alert view to work on a cell, even know it's working on a view controller.

Can someone guide me toward a tutorial, as I have difficulty to found one.

Comment: Hi Christian, I highly suggest only focusing on one problem at a time so that we can better help you solve your problems. Furthermore, you should include some code, the current behaviour of your program and the desired  one. Asking for tutorial suggestions isn't recommended as well.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you're asking too many questions in one, anyway this is a small TableView tutorial:

First thing first, you need to create your tableview:

```swift
var tableView: UITableView!
```

then you'll add it to your view:

```swift
//Put these in your view did load
//Change tose vaues as you please
tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 400), style: .plain)
view.addSubview(tableView)
```

So you'll need to register the cells:

```swift
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")  //Choose the identifier you want but always use the same within a single Table view
```

You'll have to set the delegate and the data source:

```swift
//put these in your view did load
tableView.delegate = self
tableView = self
```

And your class will need to conform to these protocolls, so, you'll add the UITableViewDelegate and the UITableViewDataSource to it:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{}
```

So you'll have to set the protocol stubs as well:

```swift
//Here you'll decide the number of cells your tableView will have
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {}
//Here you'll decide the desired output of your cell (text, color ecc...)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //You have to create the cell first, it can be done as follows:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) //Notice how I'm using the same identifier
    return cell
}
```

There are plenty of other protocol stubs like:

```swift
//Use this to determine the behaviour of the cell when you tap it
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}
//Use this to set the cell's height
private func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{}
```

You can find more in the apple documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry if I asked to many questions, I guess my question will be how can I share information between cell. I done some tutorial already, and the reusable cell do not seam the right choice, for what I want to do.